# Handling tinyInt booleans with MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, boolean

I have a mySQL table setup with a column with a datatype of TinyInt(1). This represents a boolean.

0 = false; 1 = true.

I'm also setting up a website to show this information to the company using asp.net and the MVC design. Right now, the table shows the column as:

```
"Are Records Online"| [next column]
------------------------------------
 1                  |   junk
 1                  |    junk
 0                  |  junk
```

However, I want the 1's and 0's to display as 'true/false' or 'yes/no'. Basically just something more user-friendly.

**How should I do this?** With a script on the Viewpage itself or with a foreach loop in the controller such as:

```
foreach(ListViewModel i in DefaultList)
            {
               if(i.RecordsOnline == true)
                {  //set to 'yes'
                 }
                else if(i.RecordsOnline = false)
                { //set to 'no'
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple ternary to print the appropriate bit of text in your view:

```
@(i.RecordsOnline ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use type `ENUM('yes', 'no')` instead of `TINYINT`. The same one byte per value, but more user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a DisplayTemplate based on the bool type since you appear to be converting the tinyint to bool in your model.

```
-- YesNo.cshtml
@model bool

@(Model ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Place that folder inside of ~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates

You can use it like so: (assumes RecordsOnline is part of your model and is a bool)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.RecordsOnline, "YesNo")
```